# Problemas con el popup

Tags: popup, ventana

tengo un problemilla con un popup. Yo tengo una ruta que es esta: 
http://localhost:8080/medico/informe/6.
Cuando pulso en un a href para abrir el popup, se recarga la página y la ruta pasa a ser esta:
http://localhost:8080/medico/informe/6#popup, pero no se abre el popup. Si cambio la ruta a http://localhost:8080/medico/informe/6# funciona perfectamente.
Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Pulsas un botón? Es que te faltó poner qué pulsas. Corrígelo para que quede claro el enunciado. Si es un elemento Button, asegúrate de ponerle el atributo type="button" si no, y desconozco si tiene alguna lógica, recarga la página.

Comment: Pulso un a href, el popup esta creado con css sólo pero el problema no es el popup que funciona bien sino que cuando lo pulso la primera vez no se abre  y si cambio la url como digo arriba si me lo abre

Comment: si puedes añadir el código a la pregunta sería más fácil ver el problema

Answer (score 0):

buenos dias. Favor debes ser mas especifica en que lenguaje estas trabajando. Sin embargo por deducción veo que es html, te recomiendo revisar este link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp.

Espero sea de gran ayuda.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en angularjs pero el popup lo cree con css sólo

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/